# PLS-00302: component 'EXISTS' must be declared

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm really having issues with the following function that keeps getting the error

> PLS-00302: component 'EXISTS' must be declared

when testing my function. If I delete the if statement, he gives an error with FIRST also that is has to be declared.

It would mean the world if someone could help me out!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE hr_package IS    

TYPE seniority_type_rec IS RECORD (f_name employees.first_name%TYPE, l_name 
employees.last_name%TYPE, seniority NUMBER);
TYPE seniority_table_type IS TABLE OF seniority_type_rec INDEX BY 
PLS_INTEGER;
FUNCTION calc_seniorities (p_seniority PLS_INTEGER) RETURN 
seniority_table_type ;        

END hr_package;   
/

/*  DEEL 2: PACKAGE BODY */

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY hr_package IS 


/* needs to return a list of employees with seniority over the parameter 
p_seniority using bulk sql, return type seniority_table_type with first 
name, last name and seniority*/

FUNCTION calc_seniorities (p_seniority PLS_INTEGER) 
RETURN seniority_table_type IS 
emp_table seniority_table_type;

BEGIN 
SELECT first_name, last_name, p_seniority BULK COLLECT INTO emp_table FROM 
job_history h join employees e on h.employee_id = e.employee_id WHERE 
FLOOR((MONTHS_BETWEEN(start_date,end_date))/12) >= p_seniority;
return emp_table;
END; 

END hr_package;
/

/*  DEEL 3: TESTCODE */

DECLARE
query_result hr_package.seniority_table_type;
BEGIN query_result := hr_package.calc_seniorities(5);
FOR i IN 1..query_result.COUNT LOOP
if query_result(i).exists then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(query_result(i).first_name);
end if;
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the `(i)` shifted to a wrong place and should actually be the arguments to `exists`? Move it in the right place again.

```
...
if query_result.exists(i) then
...
```

Comment: Oops yes thank you! But after placing it right again, it gives an error with FIRST saying: PLS-00302: component 'FIRST_NAME' must be declared

Comment: @AstridBagué: There is not `first_name` in your type declaration, but an `f_name`, which is presumably what you want...

Comment: Thank you very much, I adapted it! No errors anymore but it doesn't display the employees neither unfortunately :(

Comment: @Astrid, did you `set serveroutput on` prior to executing `dbms_output.put_line`? If not, you should have. If you're using some GUI tool, you'd probably have to "click" somewhere to enable it. In SQL*Plus, you'd run exactly that `set` command at the SQL> prompt.